# JQuery onkeypress ENTER

Tags: html, jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela que quando da double click em um dos seu campos ele vira um input e este input, quando pressiono enter, volta a ser um campo da tabela, porem as vezes não funciona de imediato, eu tenho que clicar no input e então apertar enter. Eu gostaria que eu pudesse clicar na celula da tabela, ela virar um input, eu alterar a informação, dar enter e ja era.

Meu codigo JS:

```
function updateFabricante(op) {
    let fabricante = $(`#fabricante${op}`).text() || $(`#fabricante`).val()

    $(`#fabricante${op}`).dblclick(function(){
        $(this).html(`<input type="text" required name="fabricante" id="fabricante" value="${fabricante}">`);
        $(`#fabricante`).focus();
    });

    $(`#fabricante`).on('keypress',function(e) {
        if(e.which === 13) {
            let fabricante = $(`#fabricante`).val();
            $(`#fabricante${op}`).html(fabricante);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

(Explicação para agilizar)

Onde

op: Especifica qual celula estou selecionando, são varias, de 0 à n

fabricante${op}: ID do campo que selecionei

fabricante: ID do input

Comment: Só para adiantar, está incorreto colocar os manipuladores de eventos dentro da função (pelo menos nesse caso). Isso porque se vc chamar mais de uma vez a função com o mesmo `op`, irá multiplicar os manipuladores, podendo ocasionar comportamento inesperado, o que parece ser o caso.

Comment: Como é que vc está chamando a função `updateFabricante` para ativar o double click?

Comment: Sim, eu notei que estava errado agora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu criei uma tabela para exemplificar o código JQuery que adaptei. Acredito que funciona para o seu caso restando apenas alterar o seletor para o seu cenário.

```js
/* Usamos $(document).ready(...) ou $(...) para garantir que todas as 
 * instruções escritas sejam aplicadas após todos os elementos 
 * do DOM (HTML) estiverem prontos para serem manipulados.
 */
$(function() {
/* Adicionando o evento de double click em todos os elementos td
 * que são filhos de qualquer elemento table.
 */
$('table td').dblclick(updateText); //Atribuindo a função updateText ao evento

/* Adicionando o evento de keypress nos elementos que tenham
 * a classe fabricante e que sejam filhos de qualquer elemento table.
 */
$('table').on('keypress', '.fabricante', function(e) {
  const key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key === 13) {
    const fabricante = $(this).val();
    $(this).replaceWith('<td>' + fabricante + '</td>'); //Trocando o elemento atual (input) por um elemento td
    $('table td').dblclick(updateText); //Adicionando o evento de double click no novo elemento td criado
  }
});

function updateText() {
  $(this).off("dblclick"); //Desabilitando o evento de double click no elemento input
  const text = $(this).text();
  $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" required name="fabricante" class="fabricante" value="' + text + '">');
  $('.fabricante').focus();
};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Idade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Flávio</td>
      <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>João</td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Você pode me explicar como esse codigo funciona, por favor? Eu não trabalhei muito com javascript nem jquery

Comment: Esta acontecendo algo engraçado comigo agora. Eu tentei utilizar seu cogido, mas não sei porque ele não funciona quadno coloco no seletor "td". Eu teste com "th" e foi, até com a table inteira ele funciona, mas se eu colocar "td" neste aqui "$('table td').dblclick(updateText);" ele não faz nada. É por isso que gostaria que me explicasse.

Comment: Eu comentei o meu código, note que para adicionar o evento de double click nos elementos eu utilizei o seletor para buscar elementos HTML (`table` e `td`). Você pode alterar para ids ou classes se ficar mais fácil. Se ainda não conseguiu entender muito bem, podemos iniciar um chat que te ajudo.

Comment: Ta certo, entendi sim. Não sei exatamente o que estava acontecendo, mas resolvi colocando tudo na função documento ready do jquery. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Essa função serve para aplicar o código javascript que estiver dentro dela logo após todo os elementos do DOM estarem disponíveis para uso.